# "Security Warning" comes up when I run via another program

Tags: automation, windows-server-2003, gui

If I execute [vmmap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx) from the command line it works fine. However, if I call some *other* program and pass vmmap as a paramater for this other program to start the execution, then I get this "security error" popup -- which makes it hard to automate scripts.

[image: Security Error]

In other words, I want to wrap vmmap via another program. In my case, I want to wrap vmmap via another program because whenever vmmap runs, it will bring a window up momentarily and then disappear. So I try passing vmmap as an argument to another program which will start the program "headlessly". I tried [this program](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/quiet/index.htm) and [this program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298564/10608), and in both cases I get the same popup which defeats the purpose of automation.

Why does this happen when the program isn't run directly? Does anyone know the internals of what this warning is? And, utlimately, is there a way to stop this from happening, but only for this instance? I don't want to disable this warning-system on my whole computer.

EDIT: I am using Windows Server 2003, and I don't necessarily need solutions for other platforms, but I would like to know what they are if they are platform-dependent solutions.

Comment: You might to clarify what versions of Windows you experience this on. The dialog itself is from `Windows Server 2003` but that hardly tells what other versions of Windows you might be using.  The instructions to do this is different between Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7.  **This is the reason the versions of Windows you are using is required.**

Comment: Here is a group policy solutionL http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e3008c75-48b4-4a6c-bc14-5a20ce72cd7f/disable-open-file-security-warning alternative solution: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning generally appears due to Zone information added to the [ADS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) of the file while downloading. The warning can be turned off using Group Policy as mentioned in the comments above, or you can **Unblock** the file from its Properties dialog, or use [**Streams**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) to delete the file's ADS.

If OTOH you see that dialog *only* when running the program using a wrapper, then looks like there might be something about those wrapper solutions that's triggering its appearance, but I'm not sure what.

Regardless, here's how I do it:

1. Run **VMMap** at least once to accept the MS/SysInternals EULA
2. Download [**NirCmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)
3. Invoke as follows using the [*exec*](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/exec.html) command (obviously replace Firefox with whatever program you're scanning):

   ```
   "C:\NirCmd\Nircmd.exe" exec hide "C:\VMMap\VMMap.exe" -p Firefox "C:\VMMap\Firefox.xml"
   ```